# MVC cache error page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, iis, routes

When there is a 404 error, my application redirects to page http://localhost:41083/hata/page-not-found

Once my page http://localhost:41083/iletisim/musterimiz-olun redirects to 404 page, even though I fix the error it still goes to 404 page, it does not hit the controller's action. However when I call the http://localhost:41083/Contact/CreateAccount page which is the same page without url rewriting it shows the page without any problem.

So is it caching the page by url? If so, how can I disable it? I am not using any output caching on the action and my site runs on IIS Express.

My Route Config and ContactController:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "musterimiz-olun",
    url: "iletisim/musterimiz-olun",
    defaults: new { controller = "Contact", action = "CreateAccount" },
    namespaces: new[] { "OyakCorporate.Controllers" }
);

public ActionResult CreateAccount()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Please provide code to verify.

Comment: Do you have default route or any other route there other then name: "musterimiz-olun"? if yes then Put this "musterimiz-olun" at the top and default route at bottom.

Comment: Yes i have so many routings and at the end of routeconfig.cs i have default route:
   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "OyakCorporate.Controllers" }
            );

Comment: Actually ı tried that but it is not working. Page was working perfectly with url rewriting and then i accidentally delete the action and then get the error. Now i fix it but it is still showing the error page. And it is not specific to this page and controller. I have the same issue on other pages sometimes.Once you have an error routing does not work. Only fix i can find is restarting the computer. I think it is somehow iis issue. But i couldnt find how to resolve it.

Comment: Please provide complete code of routeconfig.cs

Comment: here: http://www.codeshare.io/Ws1u9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Redirect() instead of RedirectPermanent() in Application_Error() method on Global.asax solved the issue.